# How to create a generic model for terms that works cross-linguistically?

Tags: morphology, lexicon, affixes, study-of-terms

I am thinking [how to create a "dictionary term" data model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081344/how-to-model-a-dictionary-term-data-model-structure-that-works-across-any-lang), and notice I don't have a real clear definition of a "term" which works across languages. Focusing on a "term" is better than a "word", because terms can be multiple words (for terms, think of anything that can be a Wikipedia page basically, a broader and more lenient definition of "term"). A "word" is, coming from English, basically anything with a space around it. I wondered what should go into an [agglutinative dictionary](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38616/what-should-go-into-a-dictionary-in-heavily-agglutinative-languages) a while back too (and [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/43736/how-a-learner-of-a-polysynthetic-language-like-arapaho-would-use-an-electronic-o) as well for examples).

My question for the Linguistics SE is, is it possible to create a standard model of "terms" or something like "concepts" (a term is basically a written concept, but then a concept is a mental term, so chicken and egg), that works across all kinds of agglutinative, analytic, etc. languages? Basically, the fundamental unit of the dictionary. If so, what would a high level description of what it should contain, include? If not, is there a way to group languages into just a few categories and have models based off each category? Or must all languages get their own model? For this question, I am wondering at a high level if it's possible, and basically what are the key things to take into consideration when trying to create a cross-linguistic dictionary.

In the Inuktitut example, we have:

```
alianaigusuttuq
he/she is having fun doing something
```

I would say (vaguely) that a binding of a subject to an action is not a term, but it could be derived from a more fundamental building block. But even then, agglutinative languages are basically (from my memory) a root and a bunch of affixes (which don't have independent meaning), so you wouldn't call those terms, but affixes I guess (I was calling them "flows" haha, everything is a "flow", and they build into trees).

So perhaps in an agglutinative scenario, the "terms" wouldn't be stored directly, they would be generated on-the-fly from a database of roots/affixes, but then the resulting response data model would be something similar to the response for an english term would give you? Is that possible, or are things just too varied to have one generic model?

It's actually surprisingly hard to model a base term or whatever for a dictionary. You'd think "oh this is obvious" and just get to modeling, but no, it's quite intricate and complex it seems :)

[This Unimorph](https://unimorph.github.io/doc/unimorph-schema.pdf) seems to offer some insight.

Comment: I suggest you go read some articles on lexicography. You say "base term" or whatever. I think you need to do some more research. In all dictionaries, the standard term for entries is the word.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the work of [Eugen Wüster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugen_W%C3%BCster) is interesting for you. He did high level work on terminology and classification systems and he published in German and Esperanto. Some of his works are available in English translations.